# SeedSequence generated by numpy 1.18 cannot be opened by numpy 1.19

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I have some random seedsequence that are generated by numpy 1.18 that are pickled into a file.

Upon upgrade, I can no longer open them with the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.random._bit_generator'

I do recognize that numpy.random._bit_generator is replaced in 1.19, but is there any method that I can still open them?

Comment: `numpy.random.bit_generator`

Comment: Yes I recognize the change to bit_generator as well. But I am not sure how I can do that with a oold seedsequence pickle file.